# XNA Skinned Model Cel-Shading coming up all black

Tags: c#, xna, shader, models, xna-4.0

I am actually making use of someone else's fix I found on Apphub (I would've asked there but apparently I have to pay their subscription to ask a question). Any ways, this person merged the Skinned Model effect with a Cel-Shading effect. They posted the Effect code but not a snippet of how to use it, so I'm not sure I'm implementing it right. I can get the model drawn on screen (even with a colored outline that the cel-shader creates), but the model is solid black. I think I may not be setting the model's texture correctly.

**Here's the cel-shading effect, unmodified from the other person.**

```
//--------------------------- BASIC PROPERTIES------------------------------  
#define MaxBones 60
float4x3 Bones[MaxBones];
// The world transformation
float4x4 World;     // The view transformation 
float4x4 View;     // The projection transformation  float4x4
Projection;     // The transpose of the inverse of the world
transformation,  // used for transforming the vertex's normal 
float4x4 WorldInverseTranspose;

//---------------------------DIFFUSE LIGHT PROPERTIES ------------------------------
// The direction of the diffuse light
float3 DiffuseLightDirection = float3(0, 0.5, 0.5);
// The color of the diffuse light
float4 DiffuseColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
// The intensity of the diffuse light
float DiffuseIntensity = 5.7;

//---------------------------TOON SHADER PROPERTIES ------------------------------
// The color to draw the lines in.  Black is a good default.
float4 LineColor = float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
// The thickness of the lines.  This may need to change, depending on the scale of
// the objects you are drawing. 
float4 LineThickness = 0.12;

//--------------------------- TEXTURE PROPERTIES ------------------------------
// The texture being used for the object
texture Texture;
// The texture sampler, which will get the texture color
sampler2D textureSampler = sampler_state  
{
    Texture = (Texture); 
    MinFilter = Linear; 
    MagFilter = Linear; 
    AddressU = Clamp; 
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

//--------------------------- DATA STRUCTURES -----------------------------
// The structure used to store information between the application and the
// vertex shader
struct AppToVertex  { 
    float4 Position : SV_Position; 
    float3 Normal   : NORMAL; 
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0; 
    int4   Indices  : BLENDINDICES0; 
    float4 Weights  : BLENDWEIGHT0;
};

// The structure used to store information between the vertex shader and the
// pixel shader 
struct VertexToPixel  { 
    float4 Position : POSITION0; 
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0; 
    float3 Normal : TEXCOORD1;
};

//SKIN Metod
void Skin(inout AppToVertex vin, uniform int boneCount) 
{ 
    float4x3 skinning = 0;

    [unroll] 
    for (int i = 0; i < boneCount; i++) 
    { 
        skinning += Bones[vin.Indices[i]] * vin.Weights[i]; 
    } 

    vin.Position.xyz = mul(vin.Position, skinning); 
    vin.Normal = mul(vin.Normal, (float3x3)skinning);
}

//--------------------------- SHADERS ------------------------------ 
// The vertex shader that does cel shading.
// It really only does the basic transformation of the vertex location,
// and normal, and copies the texture coordinate over.
VertexToPixel CelVertexShader(AppToVertex input)
{ 
    VertexToPixel output; 
    Skin(input, 4); 

    // Transform the position 
    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World); 
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View); 
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection); 

    // Transform the normal
    output.Normal = normalize(mul(input.Normal, WorldInverseTranspose)); 

    // Copy over the texture coordinate 
    output.TextureCoordinate = input.TexCoord; 

    return output;
}

// The pixel shader that does cel shading.  Basically, it calculates
// the color like is should, and then it discretizes the color into
// one of four colors.
float4 CelPixelShader(VertexToPixel input) : COLOR0
{ 
    // Calculate diffuse light amount 
    float intensity = dot(normalize(DiffuseLightDirection), input.Normal); 
    if(intensity < 0) 
        intensity = 0; 

    // Calculate what would normally be the final color, including texturing and diffuse lighting 
    float4 color = tex2D(textureSampler, input.TextureCoordinate) * DiffuseColor * DiffuseIntensity; 
    color.a = 1; 

    // Discretize the intensity, based on a few cutoff points 
    if (intensity > 0.95) 
        color = float4(1.0,1,1,1.0) * color; 
    else if (intensity > 0.5) 
        color = float4(0.7,0.7,0.7,1.0) * color; 
    else if (intensity > 0.05) 
        color = float4(0.35,0.35,0.35,1.0) * color; 
    else 
        color = float4(0.1,0.1,0.1,1.0) * color; 

    return color;
}

// The vertex shader that does the outlines
VertexToPixel OutlineVertexShader(AppToVertex input)
{ 
    VertexToPixel output = (VertexToPixel)0; 
    Skin(input, 4); 

    // Calculate where the vertex ought to be.  This line is equivalent 
    // to the transformations in the CelVertexShader. 
    float4 original = mul(mul(mul(input.Position, World), View), Projection); 

    // Calculates the normal of the vertex like it ought to be. 
    float4 normal = mul(mul(mul(input.Normal, World), View), Projection); 

    // Take the correct "original" location and translate the vertex a little 
    // bit in the direction of the normal to draw a slightly expanded object. 
    // Later, we will draw over most of this with the right color, except the expanded 
    // part, which will leave the outline that we want. 
    output.Position    = original + (mul(LineThickness, normal)); 

    return output;
}

// The pixel shader for the outline.  It is pretty simple:  draw everything with the
// correct line color. 
float4 OutlinePixelShader(VertexToPixel input) : COLOR0
{ 
    return LineColor;
}

// The entire technique for doing toon shading
technique Toon
{ 
    // The first pass will go through and draw the back-facing triangles with the outline shader,
    // which will draw a slightly larger version of the model with the outline color.  Later, the 
    // model will get drawn normally, and draw over the top most of this, leaving only an outline. 
    pass Pass1 
    { 
        VertexShader = compile vs_1_1 OutlineVertexShader(); 
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 OutlinePixelShader(); 
        CullMode = CW; 
    } 

    // The second pass will draw the model like normal, but with the cel pixel shader, which will 
    // color the model with certain colors, giving us the cel/toon effect that we are looking for. 
    pass Pass2 
    { 
        VertexShader = compile vs_1_1 CelVertexShader(); 
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 CelPixelShader(); 
        CullMode = CCW; 
    }
}
```

**And here is how I am drawing it**

```
public void Draw(Matrix viewMatrix, Matrix projectionMatrix)
    {
        Matrix[] boneTransforms = AnimPlayer.GetSkinTransforms(); //new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        Matrix worldMatrix = Orientation * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                part.Effect = celshader;
                part.Effect.CurrentTechnique = part.Effect.Techniques["Toon"];
                part.Effect.Parameters["Bones"].SetValue(boneTransforms);
                part.Effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(worldMatrix);
                part.Effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(viewMatrix);
                part.Effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projectionMatrix);
                part.Effect.Parameters["WorldInverseTranspose"].SetValue(Matrix.Transpose(Matrix.Invert(worldMatrix)));
                part.Effect.Parameters["DiffuseLightDirection"].SetValue(new Vector3(.5f));
                part.Effect.Parameters["DiffuseColor"].SetValue(Color.White.ToVector4());
                part.Effect.Parameters["DiffuseIntensity"].SetValue(1);
                part.Effect.Parameters["LineColor"].SetValue(Color.Black.ToVector4());
                part.Effect.Parameters["LineThickness"].SetValue(new Vector4(.1f));
                part.Effect.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(Texture);

                foreach (EffectPass pass in part.Effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
                {
                    part.Effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
                }
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        } 
    }
```

celshader is the Cel-Shading effect, and Texture is a loaded texture for the model. 
Any clues?

Comment: Update: Commenting out  


//part.Effect.Parameters["DiffuseLightDirection"].SetValue(new Vector3(.5f));
                    //part.Effect.Parameters["DiffuseColor"].SetValue(Color.White.ToVector4());
                    //part.Effect.Parameters["DiffuseIntensity"].SetValue(1);
                    //part.Effect.Parameters["LineColor"].SetValue(Color.Black.ToVector4());
                    //part.Effect.Parameters["LineThickness"].SetValue(new Vector4(1f));


allows colors to be shown, but now the skins are crazy messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975391(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx

You should not be assigning the effect every Draw call; do that during load time (the usual place for that is in LoadContent, but I'm not going to assume how you have yours set up).

Also, during Draw, you should typically call mesh.Draw() for each effect, as they have it in the article, not just each mesh.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error, with a simular CelShader :)

The first thing i do is i create an Effect and load the cel shader into that effect in LoadContent.

Now when you draw your model you don't want to set the different parts of the model to use a the shader(that might work to, however i haven't tried it) instead set the shader parameters here like this(Inside the foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts) loop)

```
celShader.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(texture);
celShader.Parameters["World"].SetValue(world);
celShader.Parameters["TintColor"].SetValue(Color.DarkBlue.ToVector4());
celShader.CurrentTechnique = celShader.Techniques["Toon"];
```

And also set the indices of the model and fill up the vertexbuffer to the graphicsdevice

```
graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(meshPart.VertexBuffer,meshPart.VertexOffset);
graphicsDevice.Indices = meshPart.IndexBuffer;
```

Then we can apply the shader to the model and also draws it!

```
foreach (EffectPass pass in celShader.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    graphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0,
    meshPart.NumVertices, meshPart.StartIndex, meshPart.PrimitiveCount);
}
```

that should work out any errors where the model is black.
Hope this helps

My whole drawing code:

```
public void Draw(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Effect theEffect)
    {
        Matrix[] bones = animationManager.GetBones();

        celShader.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(Camera.Proj);
        celShader.Parameters["View"].SetValue(Camera.View);

        // for each model in the mesh
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in test.Meshes)
        {
            // for each mesh part
            foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(meshPart.VertexBuffer,
                        meshPart.VertexOffset);
                graphicsDevice.Indices = meshPart.IndexBuffer;

                //here i load the texture!!!!!!!!!
                Texture2D texture = ((SkinnedEffect)meshPart.Effect).Texture;


                Matrix world = Matrix.Identity;

                celShader.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(texture);
                celShader.Parameters["World"].SetValue(world);

                celShader.Parameters["Bones"].SetValue(bones);
                celShader.Parameters["TintColor"].SetValue(Color.DarkBlue.ToVector4());

                celShader.CurrentTechnique = celShader.Techniques["Toon"];
                // for each effect pass in the cell shader
                foreach (EffectPass pass in celShader.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
                {
                    pass.Apply();

                    graphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0,
                        meshPart.NumVertices, meshPart.StartIndex, meshPart.PrimitiveCount);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the help, to both the answers. Cleaned up my code a bit. Tried drawing with both methods, yours and just simply mesh.Draw(), and I still get the same results, whacky skinning on the model (though it does appear to be celshaded). I figured an screenshot might be more helpful at this point.

http://i1231.photobucket.com/albums/ee516/Neovivacity/celshadingError.png

It may be an issue with the model having multiple skins. Straight out from the SkinnedModel tutorial it has a head, jacket, pants, etc  images for skinned parts. I'd try a new model but i'm still learning Blender.

Comment: How do you load the texture? from a file or from the mesh? i will update my post with my whole drawing code.

Comment: The textures are loaded automatically when the model is loaded (so from Mesh I assume).